# Create Microsoft Teams with a service user failed in PowerAutomate

Tags: api, office365, settings, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I try to create a Teams within Microsoft PowerAutomate. I'm using a service account and not a personal account.
When I try to create the Team I get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: 
https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, 
Request Method: POST, Response 
Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
 x-operationid: ab1805082714544fae7c028c4bf6ca3b
 x-telemetryid: 00-ab1805082714544fae7c028c4bf6ca3b-d35840089613e149-00
 X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 28FB6C881A1D4A659CE162BB06EB0F63 Ref B: VIEEDGE1108 Ref C: 2022-11- 
  23T10:55:35Z
   Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 10:55:35 GMT
 , ErrorMessage : 
  {"errors":[{"message":"Error when calling Middle Tier. Message: ''. Error 
   code: 'BadRequest'. Status code: 
   BadRequest.","errorCode":"Unknown"}],
 "operationId":"ab1805082714544fae7c028c4bf6ca3b"}
```

When the user is global O365 Admin it works, but without those rights. I get this error message.

[image: Teams Problem]

My question is what I'm doing wrong? What kind of rights need a service account to create Team? Only Global Admin?

Maybe somebody had a similar problem.

Thanks in advance Matthias

Comment: If you are using the same API query in POSTMAN or Graph Explorer, are you able to create the team?

Comment: We are able to repro that issue and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.